# How to detect differences between design and site?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10)
I put an image to understand better

[image]

The difference bothers me more background and text size.
Font used in photoshop is "ArchivoNarrow regular", this I put myself in the CSS code below

**CODE CSS:**

```
.details-footer{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: white;
  font-family: ArchivoNarrow regular;
}
```

Can you tell me please from where all these differences and how can I fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ArchivoNarrow regular` is invalid, perhaps you meant to use `"ArchivoNarrow regular"` or `"ArchivoNarrow"` but there's no guarantee the user will have this font installed, I know I don't.

Answer (score 1):

To add font, insert this in your `index.php` or whatever file, that containt links to your `css` files.
`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

You need to insert this above all other `css` links.

Then add following line to your css, where you need it:
`font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;`

For example, to apply this to the footer:
`.details-footer {
   font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
}`

Done!

*P.S.: It's not a good idea to upload the font to your server, you should use Google Fonts when you can.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the font? If not you do so like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

then you need to upload the .woff font file to your folder.

Comment: Archivo Narrow font is not a default?

Comment: No, if you want to use that font you would have to upload it and define it as above. Otherwise you can use an alternative font which is default:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: Looks like Archivo Narow is available as a [fontface kit on FontSquirrel.](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/archivo-narrow)